# Can't increment a static variable

Tags: c++

Could you help me understand why I can't increment the static variable?
I face this: *error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static unsigned int Counter::m_curCounters" (?m_curCounters@Counter@@0IA)*

**counter.cpp**

```
#include "counter.h"

static unsigned int m_curCounters = 0;

Counter::Counter(const char* p){
    ...
    m_curCounters++;
}


Counter::Counter(){
    ...
    m_curCounters++;
}
```

Comment: try ::m_curCounters++;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think whats happening here that you have `m_curCounters` declared in `counter.h` and that you create a new local static in the cpp.
But class statics need to be visible to the linker by defining them in the cpp as `unsigned int Counter::m_curCounters = 0;`

Now when you try to use the local static the compiler gives precedence to the class static which the linker cant find later on

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you have `m_curCounters` declared in Counter.
Then you need to define it as

```
unsigned int Counter::m_curCounters = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you gave us half the code, it's time for some psychic debugging!  Here's what I think you have in your header file:

```
class Counter
{
    static unsigned int m_curCounters;
};
```

Therefore, in your .cpp file you have forgotten to define the static variable within the scope of your class.  You need:

```
unsigned int Counter::m_curCounters = 0;
```

Comment: It won't compile definition with static.